# A UIInterfaceOrientation issue

Tags: ios, uiinterfaceorientation

I want my iPhone app to globally behave as if only the UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait was permitted.
But at the same time I want it to be aware of the physical orientation in order to react in a specific way, only within a limited area of the display.
How can I get this?

I did some tests using the self.interfaceOrientation iVar of the UIViewController, but that does not seem to work, because this variable does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do `[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications]`.  Then register for `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`.  When you receive the notification, check `[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation` for the device's physical orientation.

You should definitely read the documentation for these APIs, because it contains some important warnings.

Also note that device orientation is returned as a `UIDeviceOrientation`, which is different than a `UIInterfaceOrientation`.  Keep in mind this information from the `UIInterfaceOrientation` documentation:

> You use these constants in the `statusBarOrientation` property and the `setStatusBarOrientation:animated:` method. Notice that `UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight` is assigned to `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft` and `UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft` is assigned to `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight`; the reason for this is that rotating the device requires rotating the content in the opposite direction.